# Will php -l checking work on PHP files of older/past and future PHP versions?

Tags: php

For example I have a PHP 5.2 php.exe which I'm using to run the syntax checks of several PHP files - this works fine (have not had any problems) - but this may be because the files which I checked were PHP 5.2 files...

So I was wondering what would happen if I checked the syntax of lets say *functional* PHP 4 files or PHP 5.2+ files - *in all instances* would the check be fine or produce errors?

I would imagine checking pre PHP 5.2 files (like PHP 4 etc) would be fine (as PHP is obviously backwards compatible and I'm assuming php - l does not take function names into account when checking; so deprecated functions won't be an issue)...but I can see that the checking of PHP 5.2+ files could be an issue though, would I be correct in saying that; it would work fine on PHP files of older/past PHP versions but not future?

Comment: Syntax has changed considerably between 5.2 and 5.3, for example.

Comment: @Maerlyn agreed - I've updated/rectified my original question, would appreciate if you could review and reply with your thoughts?

Comment: You can check compatibility from previous version (but not in the sense I believe you're talking about), but not future. When your 5.2 binary was created, it wasn't given all future features planned for new version of PHP. You could install each version binary and use that to check your files against each version. From what you're saying though, you want to create a PHP file which will work across most versions of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to say with any certainty that a PHP 4 file will work with PHP 5.2 or that a PHP 5.4 file will work with PHP 5.2.  There have been many changes between the versions.

**From newer version to older version**

If you have a script written in 5.4 you will have no problems with that script in 5.2 IF and ONLY IF the script doesn't include any new functions introduced in 5.3 or 5.4.

**From older version to newer version**

If you have a script written in PHP 4.x and you want to use it in PHP 5.2 for the most part there won't be issues but there are some backward incompatible changes.

Here are the migration guides for you:

[Migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php)

[Migrating from PHP 5.0.x to PHP 5.1.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration51.php)

[Migrating from PHP 5.1.x to PHP 5.2.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration52.php)

[Migrating from PHP 5.3.x to PHP 5.4.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.php)

[Migrating from PHP 5.4.x to PHP 5.5.x](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.php)